# I'm trying to send email to multiple recipients using a REST API call

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, email, triggered-send

When I use the messageDefinitionSends/.../sendBatch API call, that I learned about on Stack Exchange, to send email to multiple recipients, email is only sent to the last recipient on the list and only data for the last recipient is logged into the data extension. I know that this API call is not supported by Marketing Cloud, but does anyone know if this call actually works? Any suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks.

Here is the API call and the payload I used:

```
POST https://EndPoint.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:{KeyValue}/sendBatch

[{
"To": {
    "Address": "john@domain.com",
    "SubscriberKey": "john@domain.com",
      "ContactAttributes": {
        "SubscriberAttributes": {
            "BorrowerFirstName": "John"
       }
      }
    },
"To": {
    "Address": "jim@domain.com",
    "SubscriberKey": "jim@domain.com",
      "ContactAttributes": {
        "SubscriberAttributes": {
            "BorrowerFirstName": "Jim"
       }
      }
    },
    "Options": {
    "RequestType": "ASYNC"
}
}]
```

Comment: That is a deprecated approach. The current and officially supported way is via [Transactional Messaging](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/310536/send-a-transactional-message-via-api-with-automatically-created-unique-identifie)

Comment: I don't think this is a deprecated approach. Transactional messaging still does not have feature parity with regular TSDs.  While using `sendBatch` has issues (sendlog, exclusion scripts, etc.), using multiple calls to the `send` endpoint is still the best, IMO.

Comment: Thank you, both. I structured arrays in the payload two different ways, and each one worked half way - only one email sent. Our only choice may be to use multiple API calls with the 'send' endpoint, which is how we typically do it.